PolarDB 11 compiles pg_bulkload plugin but reports an error
I am encountering a compilation error when trying to build the pg_bulkload plugin with PolarDB 11. Here's a detailed description of the steps I followed and the errors encountered
Reproduction Steps:

Set Up PolarDB Development Environment:


I set up a PolarDB development environment by compiling and installing PolarDB 11 from the source.Pulled a Docker image for PolarDB development on a familiar OS, such as Ubuntu 22.04:

docker pull registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/polardb_pg/polardb_pg_devel:ubuntu22.04      


Created and ran a container:

docker run -d -it -P --shm-size=1g --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --privileged=true --name polardb_pg_devel registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/polardb_pg/polardb_pg_devel:ubuntu22.04 bash      


Entered the container:

# 进入容器    
docker exec -ti polardb_pg_devel bash      


Cloned PolarDB 11 source code and deployed the PolarDB-PG instance:

# 例如这里拉取 POLARDB_11_STABLE 分支;     
# PS: 截止2024.9.24 PolarDB开源的最新分支为: POLARDB_15_STABLE      
cd /tmp       
git clone -c core.symlinks=true --depth 1 -b POLARDB_11_STABLE https://github.com/ApsaraDB/PolarDB-for-PostgreSQL      
    
# 编译PolarDB 11并初始化实例    
cd /tmp/PolarDB-for-PostgreSQL      
./polardb_build.sh --without-fbl --debug=off      
      
# 验证PolarDB-PG      
psql -c 'SELECT version();'        
      
            version                   
--------------------------------      
 PostgreSQL 11.9 (POLARDB 11.9)      
(1 row)    
    
# 在容器内关闭、启动PolarDB数据库方法如下:       
pg_ctl stop -m fast -D ~/tmp_master_dir_polardb_pg_1100_bld         
pg_ctl start -D ~/tmp_master_dir_polardb_pg_1100_bld        

2.Inside the container, downloaded the pg_bulkload source code:
cd /tmp    
git clone -c core.symlinks=true --depth 1 https://github.com/ossc-db/pg_bulkload  


Compile pg_bulkload:
Attempted to compile pg_bulkload:

cd /tmp/pg_bulkload    
USE_PGXS=1 make install    

Error Messages:
In file included from /home/postgres/tmp_basedir_polardb_pg_1100_bld/include/server/storage/pg_shmem.h:30,  
                 from recovery.c:29:  
/home/postgres/tmp_basedir_polardb_pg_1100_bld/include/server/utils/hsearch.h:78:9: error: unknown type name ‘MemoryContext’  
   78 |         MemoryContext hcxt;                     /* memory context to use for allocations */  
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~  
make[1]: *** [<builtin>: recovery.o] Error 1  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/pg_bulkload/bin'  
make: *** [Makefile:27: all] Error 2  

The error message should be due to the lack of a header file reference containing memoryContext. After searching the code, I found this definition in utils/palloc.h.
/home/postgres/tmp_basedir_polardb_pg_1100_bld/include/server/utils/palloc.h    
  
... ...  
 /*  
  * Type MemoryContextData is declared in nodes/memnodes.h.  Most users  
  * of memory allocation should just treat it as an abstract type, so we  
  * do not provide the struct contents here.  
  */  
 typedef struct MemoryContextData *MemoryContext;  
... ...   

Modified recovery.c to include the missing header:
vi bin/recovery.c  
  
... ...  
#include "storage/bufpage.h"  
// 新增一个 include :    
#include "utils/palloc.h"  
#include "storage/pg_shmem.h"  
... ...  

After fixing the first error, a new error appeared:
cd /tmp/pg_bulkload    
USE_PGXS=1 make install    
  
# 报错如下:  
writer_binary.c: In function ‘open_output_file’:  
writer_binary.c:430:14: error: too few arguments to function ‘BasicOpenFilePerm’  
  430 |         fd = BasicOpenFilePerm(fname, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL | PG_BINARY,  
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
In file included from /home/postgres/tmp_basedir_polardb_pg_1100_bld/include/server/utils/sharedtuplestore.h:17,  
                 from /home/postgres/tmp_basedir_polardb_pg_1100_bld/include/server/nodes/execnodes.h:27,  
                 from ../include/reader.h:18,  
                 from ../include/binary.h:15,  
                 from writer_binary.c:19:  
/home/postgres/tmp_basedir_polardb_pg_1100_bld/include/server/storage/fd.h:115:17: note: declared here  
  115 | extern int      BasicOpenFilePerm(const char *fileName, int fileFlags, mode_t fileMode, bool polar_vfs);  
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
make[1]: *** [<builtin>: writer_binary.o] Error 1  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/pg_bulkload/lib'  
make: *** [Makefile:27: all] Error 2  

It seems that the BasicOpenFilePerm called by pg_bulkload has been modified by PolarDB and is incompatible with PostgreSQL 11.
How to solve this error?
